# How do i make procedular "stains" on the top of walls

Tags: texturing, node-editor

i want it to look something like this

[image]

Comment: This is the second time you've asked such a question. Strictly speaking, this type of question is not really welcome on this Q&A platform because it is not targeted enough and does not clearly define what the starting point is. There are simply too many possibilities for an answer, making the question not only unclear, but also difficult to find by other users. Please take a very close look at [how a good question should be asked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/asking) without being closed. So please be so kind and edit your question to be able to open it again. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @hennayaz! Are you looking to _simulate_, for example, where stains would naturally appear on structures, as the result of rainfall / leaks? If so, could you make that clear, and give some indication of approaches you have taken yourself, or others you have seen?  Some sort of clarification like that, of what _exactly_ you are looking for, so folks can try to answer more specifically, would repair this question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/209762/110840

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very quick and dirty solution (excuse the pun). You can play around with the texture settings and coloramp positions to get closer to the reference.

It's not ideal, especially if realism is the priority, but can work in a pinch. If proceduralism isn't a dealbreaker check out Quixel megasans - they have a ton of free leak, stain and grunge alphas you can use to create this effect quickly and convincingly.

[image]
[image]